# Filling in missing age values in NLSY79 data with Stata

Tags: stata

The NLSY79 is a panel survey that records an individual's age but in some years it will skip the question and code it as -5. The dataset is annual between 1979 and 1994 and then becomes biennial through 2012. So sample data for an individual may look like this:

```
caseid_1979 year    age
73          1988    25
73          1989    26
73          1990    -5
73          1991    -5
73          1992    -5
73          1993    30
73          1994    30
73          1996    32
73          1998    -5
73          2000    36
```

So my question is how can I program Stata so that the missing age values are filled in? I realize that in some years the person's birthday has not yet occurred so the age might be repeated in consecutive years and am not sure what to do (if anything) about that.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, we can be confident that age is, or should be, linear in year for each individual. So we have an exercise in interpolation.

```
 clonevar age2 = age 
 replace age2 = . if age2 == -5 
 ipolate age2 year, generate(age3) by(caseid_79) epolate
 bysort caseid_79 (year) : assert age3 == age3[1] + (year - year[1])
```

If you want to allow a tolerance of 1 year, say

```
bysort caseid_79 (year) : assert inlist(age3 - age3[1] + year - year[1], 0, 1)
```

See also [this FAQ, which discusses replaces missing values in sequences](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/replacing-missing-values/index.html)